# Does the north pole of the Solar System (with respect to the invariable plane) point towards the galactic center?

Tags: the-sun, galaxy, solar-system, milky-way, galaxy-center

How is our Solar System as a whole (not the wobbly Earth) tilted with respect to the invariable plane of the Milky Way?

I understand our Sun's north pole is largely pointing towards our direction of orbit around the Milky Way, (I think), but, how much is it tilted (if at all) with respect to the 'north' or 'south' of the galaxy?

When other sites say we are tilted about 60° to 62° or so, which direction do they mean?

Comment: you obviously DID do research on what sources say. But maybe you can share with us the sources so that we can make an informed decision on those you consulted? Thus please edit the question by inserting links to your references :)

Comment: I have been asking myself basically this same question!  As best I know our solar system is 'North' of the galactic plane and our solar system ecliptic is 60 deg(ish) tipped from the galactic plane... but there seems to be a missing criteria needed to fully define orientation.

Comment: ya planetmaker's suggestion is spot-on. We usually talk about "evidence of prior research" for several reasons; 1) it helps potential answer authors to know where you've checked so far so that each doesn't end up duplicating your effort, 2) it helps potential answer authors to judge how and at what level to write an answer, and 3) it sets a good example for other users who might get the idea that its okay to not do prior research (e.g. "Look at this question, they didn't do any, why should I?")